# how to migrate opencart 1.5.6 database to 2.3.0.0

Tags: opencart, opencart2.3

I have decided to upgrade my `opencart` website. But the problem is there is lot of changes in database of both version. How can I do this in a good and fast way?

Answer (score 0):

download 2.3, run the upgrade script.